# Create new column in Excel based on previous column data

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Just a disclaimer: I have limited experience with Excel and sql... I'm basically a noob, so bear with me.

I have a big Excel spreadsheet that is sent to me daily that I would like to manipulate.

I would like to add a couple columns that create values based on their respective rows.

```
ID  Color   Brand   Indicator
1   Green   Vizio   TRUE
2   Yellow  Samsung FALSE
3   Blue    Samsung TRUE
4   Red     Sony    FALSE
5   Orange  Vizio   TRUE
```

In the example above, the Indicator column is the one that I'd like to be created based on the values in the previous columns.  The Indicator should be true if Brand has the word Vizio in it, OR if the color is Blue. I mention it has to have the word vizio in it because there are cases where it won't be simply "vizio", but maybe "vizio tv".

I would like to automate this process as much as possible, so do you think it would be best to use an Excel VBA macro or SQL for this?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which database you are using

Comment: I will do this using computed column, If my database supports computed column. `Indicator as (case when Brand like '%Vizio%' or Color = 'Blue' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end)`

Comment: Another formula that can be used in VBA: `=OR(EXACT(B2,"Blue"),EXACT(C2,"Vizio"))`

Comment: @paulbica Your formula is not going to work in, as the OP writes, ***cases where it won't be simply "vizio", but maybe "vizio tv"***.

Comment: Thanks @ExcelHero - misinterpreted the question. Then using IsNumber: `=OR(EXACT(B2,"Blue"),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Vizio*",C2)),TRUE, FALSE))`

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Excel macro.

```
Public Sub AddIndicators()
    Const INDICATOR_1_COLUMN = 4
    Const INDICATOR_1_FORMULA = "=OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(""vizio"",C2),0),(B2=""blue""))"

    [a2:index(a:a,counta(a:a))].Offset(, INDICATOR_1_COLUMN - 1) = INDICATOR_1_FORMULA
End Sub
```

This can easily be expanded for additional indicator columns.

To have this macro available to run whenever you receive your daily worksbooks (and without the need to add the macro to the incoming workbook) simply add this macro to your [Personal Workbook](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566).

After that is done, just make sure your daily workbook is open and on the sheet where you want the indicators before executing the macro.

If perchance you do not wish for the formulas to remain in the indicator column, you can use this version of the macro instead:

```
Public Sub AddIndicators()
    Const INDICATOR_1_COLUMN = 4
    Const INDICATOR_1_FORMULA = "=OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(""vizio"",C2),0),(B2=""blue""))"

    With [a2:index(a:a,counta(a:a))].Offset(, INDICATOR_1_COLUMN - 1)
        .Formula = INDICATOR_1_FORMULA
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The user receives excel sheet in mail. So macro or vscript need to be created in the "received excel" or data need to copy-pasted from "received excel" to vB script excel. these unnecessary task reduce the level of automation.

Comment: @seahawk Please stop. This is unproductive. As suggested, macro will reside in the Personal Workbook, not the incoming workbook. It can be executed with no additional work.

Comment: You are saying the same what I have already said. Macro will reside in the Personal Workbook and data will reside in incoming workbook. Either macro should be moved from personal workbook to incoming workbook or data from incoming to personal because inter-workbook macro is NOT written here. Hence the process is not automated as you have explained.

Comment: @seahawk This macro is written to work on the currently active workbook. Although it will reside in the Personal workbook, it will function on whichever workbook is visible inside Excel. It works as I have described. Your understanding has gaps leading to poor comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is very simple. You don't have to go for VBscript, macros etc. It can be simply done with excel functions.

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("blue",B2)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("vizio",C2))))
```

Assumption: Color is in column B and Brand is in column c and data starts from row 2. First row is for headers.

Comment: Of course it can. But OP specifically stated that he wishes to ***automate this process as much as possible...*** so this is not an appropriate solution since it would require manually adding the formulas each day when the workbook arrives.

Comment: @ExcelHero : I disagree with you. If data is present in excel sheet. "Indicator" column will be populated by putting the above mentioned formula and clicking at bottom-right corner of the cell. And Bingo, its done. Field sequence should be same as in this question.

Comment: @ExcelHero : copy-paste single line code is easier than creating a vbscript/macro or copy-paste full data from one sheet to other.